# JQuery Datatables; how do I include an optional delete link and avoid showing "Click to Edit"?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have 2 problems with using the datatable below;

```
    var otable = $('#tradeList').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": serverDataSource,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "iDisplayLength": "15",

        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
                     {
                         "sName": "ID",
                         "bSearchable": false,
                         "bSortable": false,
                         "bVisible": false
                     },
                     { "sName": "TRADENAME" },
                    {
                        "sName": "TRADEID",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                            // oObj.aData[2] returns the TradeId
                            if (oObj.aData[2] == "0")
                                //return "<a href='" + deleteUrl + "?id=" + oObj.aData[2] + "'>Delete</a>";
                                return "<button onclick=" + dataService.deleteTrade(oObj.aData[2], fnDraw, deleteUrl ) + ")>";
                            else
                                return "";
                        }
                    }
            ]
        }).makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: updateUrl,
        sAddURL: addUrl,
        sDeleteURL: deleteUrl
    });
```

The delete button is optional. So when I do not want to show it, how do I stop the default "Click to Edit" text showing. I can see it come from the Jquery library jeditable.
The second problem I shall ask in a seperate question.

Answer (score 0):

to remove "Click to edit" you must configure the propertie 'placeholder' to empty inside the makeEditable function. In your case would be:

```
var otable = $('#tradeList').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": serverDataSource,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "iDisplayLength": "15",

    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumns": [
                 {
                     "sName": "ID",
                     "bSearchable": false,
                     "bSortable": false,
                     "bVisible": false
                 },
                 { "sName": "TRADENAME" },
                {
                    "sName": "TRADEID",
                    "bSearchable": false,
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                        // oObj.aData[2] returns the TradeId
                        if (oObj.aData[2] == "0")
                            //return "<a href='" + deleteUrl + "?id=" + oObj.aData[2] + "'>Delete</a>";
                            return "<button onclick=" + dataService.deleteTrade(oObj.aData[2], fnDraw, deleteUrl ) + ")>";
                        else
                            return "";
                    }
                }
        ]
    }).makeEditable({
    sUpdateURL: updateUrl,
    sAddURL: addUrl,
    sDeleteURL: deleteUrl,
    aoColumns: [
    {
        placeholder : ""
    },
    {
        placeholder : ""
    },
    {
        placeholder : ""
    }
]
});
```