# jquery Datatables - how do I put in a delete link?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Another question has been asked on this, [jQuery Datatables: how to delete the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214307/jquery-datatables-how-to-delete-the-row), but I am struggling to get the syntax right.

What should I be doing instead of creating a button as below?

```
    var otable = $('#tradeList').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": serverDataSource,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "iDisplayLength": "15",

        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
                     {
                         "sName": "ID",
                         "bSearchable": false,
                         "bSortable": false,
                         "bVisible": false
                     },
                     { "sName": "TRADENAME" },
                    {
                        "sName": "TRADEID",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                            // oObj.aData[2] returns the TradeId
                            if (oObj.aData[2] == "0")
                                //return "<a href='" + deleteUrl + "?id=" + oObj.aData[2] + "'>Delete</a>";
                                return "<button onclick=" + dataService.deleteTrade(oObj.aData[2], fnDraw, deleteUrl ) + ")>";
                            else
                                return "";
                        }
                    }
            ]
        }).makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: updateUrl,
        sAddURL: addUrl,
        sDeleteURL: deleteUrl
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Datatables; how do I include an optional delete link and avoid showing "Click to Edit"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560993/jquery-datatables-how-do-i-include-an-optional-delete-link-and-avoid-showing-c)

Comment: No, this is a different issue. There are 2 things wrong with the above code, so I am asking about each issue seperately. This question has nothing to do with "Click to Edit"

Comment: You need to use `return "<button onclick=" + dataService.deleteTrade(oObj.aData[2], fnDraw, deleteUrl ) + ")>Delete<button>";`

Comment: Yes, that fixes one bug, so thank you for that. The issue now is fnDraw is not recognised, so I will look into that next.